# How to set background color of button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

How to set the background color of a button in xaml?

It can't be much harder than

```
<Button Margin="2" Background ="LightGreen" ....>
```

But this does not work...for the avoidance of confusion, button here is `System.Windows.Controls.Button`

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that I use DevExpress's ThemeManager but did not think that would cause issues as per DevExpress they do not style the standard Windows Buttons...apparently they do, however, which basically makes it impossible to change the background color of a button without some major work...

Comment: Is there any theming approach in your project ?

Comment: Yes, DevExpress ThemeManager...

Comment: @Downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: By not working, what do you mean? (I'm not the downvoter btw)

Comment: Could you explain how do you use ThemeManager? Are you sure you're not changing button's style or template? The method you already tried is the normal way to do this, unless you're not changing the background somewhere else.

Comment: @J.Swietek, I use it as part of my xaml Window declaration `dx:ThemeManager.Theme="MetropolisDark"`

Comment: Does "MetropolisDark" theme contain any styles for buttons? That might be interfering with you, setting the background on the button.

Comment: @MattWolf Wolf This may help you : https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q399125

Comment: @J.Swietek, that is what I am suspecting...but DevExpress insists they do not style the standard Windows Button...

Comment: @Thirisangu, thanks and it seems it is impossible to to change the background color in this case unless I want to re-write an entire theme and style library....goodness...

Comment: @MattWolf Good luck :)

Comment: Reflect extremely poorly on DevExpress I would say...and I will definitely not waste precious hours just to change a button background color...but thanks for pointing me into the right direction. Please feel free to write up a one-line answer and I am happy to accept.

Comment: Did u have look, there should be a property named as "LookAndFeelLayout". You should play around it, https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2184

Comment: @Ugur, this is Winforms specific and does not exist in WPF. WPF deals with Themes/Theming. And the only way to get around this problem seems to be writing a custom Theme. It makes no sense to me as not everyone wants all the buttons look the same identical way. It is a weird concept DevExpress applies here. But then they pretty much totally misunderstood one of the core ideas of WPF and MVVM which is data binding and messed up most of their WPF from the ground up...unfortunately I inherited projects that use this specific vendor and do not have a choice...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfCoreThemeManagertopic):

> DevExpress provides multiple themes that can be applied to all
>   DevExpress controls for WPF and some standard controls (GroupBox,
>   ScrollViewer, Scroll, RadoiButton, Button, ListBox, Slider,
>   TabControl, Separator, ToggleButton, RepeatButton, Label, ListBoxItem,
>   TabItem, ToolTip, etc).

As you can see the `Button` control is listed here. But then in documentation it is said that you can disable theme of individual control by setting `ThemeName` attribute to `None`. So, you can just disable the theme for button or for some of its parent containers and use your own style.
Here is example:

```
<Button Margin="2" Background="LightGreen" dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="None" ...>
```

Comment: Its amazing what a quick glance over the actual documentation can yield, you just solved my problem. I never even checked because DevExpress's own staff in the support forum insisted this cannot be done. Thanks a lot for this. Quick and clean solution.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
yourBtn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```

Or in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BG" Color="Green"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Background="{DynamicResource BG}"></Button>
```

Comment: I asked specifically for a xaml solution!

Comment: that said, try setting the background that way, just to see if it works. Then you'll know it's a problem with your xaml rather than some weird configuration thing that's stopping buttons from being coloured properly

Comment: Why `Grid.Resources`?

Comment: @MattWolf ... To define `SolidColorBrush`.

Comment: Does not work either. I think there is a problem when using the DevExpress ThemeManager. It seems to override certain things...though they stress that the `Windows Button` is not part of their style library

Comment: Does your button exist inside a grid ? to call Grid.Ressources ??

Comment: @MattWolf...as @Med.Amine.Touil said if your button isn't inside a grid put the `SolidColorBrush` in `Window.Resources` and test it again. Check my updated answer.

Comment: In theory it should work whatever the theme manager is (xceed,devexpress...)

Answer (score 0):

`<Button Margin="2" Background="LightGreen"/>` works. If it doesn't work for you, perhaps you have another `style` or style manager overriding it somewhere.

Additional information - Another answer shows how to style an individual button using dynamic resources. To set the background colour for all buttons in a style using a resourcedictionary, you can use something like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <!--background brush-->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="backgroundBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.3"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDFF" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

        <!--The style for buttons-->
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource backgroundBrush}"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `<Button Margin="2" Background="LightGreen" ....>` with such as `Your code ` or simply `It` to make it as short as possible.

Comment: @KingKing I don't quite know what you're getting at? Surely an answer with full code in is better for people who look at this in the future (especially if the original question gets edited at some point)

Comment: You're the one who do not understand what I meant (or maybe ***implied***). This is not even an answer and be careful to avoid downvotes being thrown on this. Some comments of mine are even 3-4 times longer than this.

Comment: aha sarcasm, fair enough. I am planning on updating it as the OP provides more details - but a valid answer to "How to set the background color of a button in xaml?" is, in my opinion, `<Button Margin="2" Background="LightGreen"/>`

Comment: @simonalexander2005, so my question remains the same: How can I set the color in xaml. I **do not want** to set the color via a StaticResource.

Comment: @MattWolf then `<Button Margin="2" Background="LightGreen"/>` should work, and I don't know why it doesn't without seeing more details of your code. Have you tried making a new WPF project with one button in it, using exactly that code, and seeing if it works?

Comment: @simonalexander2005, I figured out that it is related to DevExpress's ThemeManager. Though they stress that the Button of the Windows.Controls is not styled by them...

Comment: then you can write your own answer and mark it as the answer :)

Comment: @simonalexander2005, I did not state that I want **all** my buttons to be styled, something your solution does. And why should I write my own answer? I asked a question and do not know the answer hence I asked. Just because a ThemeManager is involved does not solve my problem. I need a specific button to be of a specific background color

Comment: yes, the theme solution I provided would do that. You can change that behaviour by specifying a key for the style, and applying it specifically to the buttons you want to apply it to. But then you would need a default style to use otherwise. I just suggested some different solutions, that's all :) - and I did also say that the code you suggest in your question should work - so I also provided a valid answer

Comment: @simonalexander2005, no it does not, I tried it out. Nothing changes.