# Button background no showing in menuitem

Tags: wpf, menuitem, stackpanel

I have a Menuitem that contains a stackPanel which contains several button. I try to apply different background colors to the buttons, but none of them are showing.

Here is my code:

```
...
<MenuItem>
<MenuItem.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Gray">
        <Button Background="Red" Width="30" Height="30"/>
        <Button Background="Blue" Width="30" Height="30"/>
        <Button Background="Green" Width="30" Height="30"/>
    </StackPanel>
</MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
...
```

However, The StackPanel's background showed up just fine.
I tried to only adding 1 button to the MenuItem Header. Still no color. anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Could you create a window with this menu, and show the whole XAML definition for the window?

Comment: Have you already tried setting the background color of a single button without any menu around? Are you satisfied with the result? I see no need to dive into this special case for now.

Comment: Kennyzx, Turns out this only happens to context menu. I created a regular menu with menu item and it works just fine.

Comment: I tested it further, It seems to work fine when I try to add a context menu to native WPF controls. What I was trying to achieve was adding a context menu with buttons I mentioned above to a DevExpress tile control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that when you put a button inside any Devexpress control will disallowed the ability to set the button's background.

I found the solution to this problem in this other [StackOverFlow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213025/how-to-set-background-color-of-button-in-wpf)

Basically we need to set the button's theme to none:

```
<Button Margin="2" Background="LightGreen" dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="None" ...>
```